How to Textjoin on resetting row number
Im trying to use the textjoin function in excel. i want to merge the text if column A is same and column B is same, then it should merge column G with an resetting counter on column E.
I hope the picture describes it more clearly
enter image description here

What have you tried? Please search the net for "using if function in excel"!

hi, I've tried many different IF text joins but couldn't get it to work, now there's a link to the image.

What should happen, if there are three or more rows with same matching values?

It should continue to text join, max is 17 in column E

If you need more than two rows to be concantenated you can use a helper column like this:

Column A: id1 your first identifier
Column B: id2 your second identifier
Column C: text the text to be concatenated
Column D: helper: recursively concatenate with row below: 
=IF(AND(A2=A3; B2=B3); C2 & " - " & D3; C2) starting in cell D2
Column E: result: only show first row of matching block: 
=IF(AND(A2=A1; B2=B1); ""; D2) starting in cell E2

Result:

If you have a non-english version of Excel you will have to translate the function names IF and AND accordingly.
